# Avoiding repetition / loop unswitching

Tags: c, optimization, dry

I have hotspot code which runs in a tight loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < big; i++)
{
    if (condition1) {
        do1();
    } else if (condition2) {
        do2();
    } else {
        do3();
    }
    // Shared code goes here
    // More shared code goes here
}
```

Since `condition1` and `condition2` are invariant, I unswitched the loop to

```
if (condition1) {
    for (i = 0; i < big; i++)
    {
        do1();
        // Shared code goes here
        // More shared code goes here
    }
} else if (condition 2) {
    for (i = 0; i < big; i++)
    {
        do2();
        // Shared code goes here
        // More shared code goes here
    }
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < big; i++)
    {
        do3();
        // Shared code goes here
        // More shared code goes here
    }
}
```

This runs much better, but I wonder if there's a clever way to do this without repeating myself?

Comment: Perhaps you could use a function pointer. Set that based on the conditions, then use that inside a single loop.

Comment: Are condition1 and condition2 known at compile time?

Comment: @Straw1239: No, they may differ each time the function is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another, possibly slightly more efficient option is to use a macro to construct the code for you:

```
#define DO_N(name, ...) for(int i = 0; i < big; i++){name(__VA_ARGS__);/*shared code*/}

if (condition1) {
    DO_N(do1, .../*arguments here*/)
} else if (condition 2) {
    DO_N(do2, ...)
} else {
    DO_N(do3, ...)
}

#undef DO_N
```

Its ugly, but I think it does what you want, and might allow inlining where a function pointer does not.

Additionally, you may find it more readable to put your shared code in a separate macro or function.

Comment: See [my other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35161175/avoiding-repetition-loop-unswitching#comment58041402_35161313), where the calls through function pointers are (potentially) inlined. It's worth measuring and playing around with linkage before coming to performance conclusions.

Comment: @chris I saw that, and its good to know that compilers are good at that. I wasn't sure, so I said "might".

Comment: Yeah, I would definitely be wary of assuming they *will* be inlined just as easily. To my knowledge, function pointers are a lot more hit-and-miss, and it looks to me like GCC needed a bit of prodding, to the point where it could eliminate the function completely.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can declare a function pointer and some function `foo()`:

```
typedef void (*fp)(void);

void foo(int big, fp f) {
    for (int i = 0; i < big; ++i) {
        f();
        // Shared code goes here
        // More shared code goes her
    }
}
```

Then change your code for something like this:

```
if (condition1) {
    foo(big, do1);
} else if (condition2) {
    foo(big, do2);
} else {
    foo(big, do3);
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea. But (sorry!) I forgot to mention that in my code `do1`, `do2`, and `do3` have different signatures.

Comment: @Charles, Since `do1(); do2();  do3();` in the post all take the same arguments (none), this answer well answers this post. Maybe post another with your added restrictions.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: I'll +1 you for the correct answer to this, and see if anyone has a solution which applies to my case. Thanks!

Comment: @Charles Be aware that the downside with this solution (from a performance standpoint) is that the function cannot be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: @VilleKrumlinde, With a contrived example, GCC [inlines `static` functions](http://goo.gl/qWeH01) (or `inline` ones) and Clang [inlines all of them](http://goo.gl/9S3Ra4). That's not to say function pointers are easy to inline, but they can be.

Comment: @chris Thanks for the examples, I learned something new! So my comment should have been "is less likely to be inlined" rather than "cannot".

Comment: @chris Nice example!